# process statuse is sombi after kill the process that opened in python subprocess.Popen and killed by subprocess.kill

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, popen, kill

I'm using python with subprocess.Popen()  to start FFmpeg with input live radio streaming URL and makes wav file every 30 seconds.
When I try to kill the process with subprocess.kill() it works, But the process is still write in /proc/ and if I check-in system monitor the status of the process is "Zombi".

Until the python script is done, So the process removed from /proc and I don't see it in the system monitor.

How can I kill the process without closed the python script?

here is example

```
#! /usr/bin/python3 
import os
import subprocess
import time

# Start ffmpeg in background.
folder_name = "path_to_file"
input_ = "https://kanlivep2event-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/749629/749629/kanmoreshet_mp3/chunklist.m3u8"
ffmpeg_cmd = [
        "ffmpeg",
        "-y",
        "-loglevel", "8",
        "-thread_queue_size", "1500",
        "-i", input_,
        "-c", "copy",
        "-vn",
        "-f", "segment",
        "-segment_time", "30",
        "-ar", "8000",
        "-acodec", "pcm_s32le",
        "-ac", "1",
        "-strftime", "1",
        str(folder_name + '/' + input_.replace("/","") + '_*_*_%s.wav')
    ]
process = subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_cmd)
# Check if the process is exist
def check_exist(process):
    print("pid - ", process.pid)
    if os.path.isdir("/proc/{}".format(process.pid)):
        print ("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")

check_exist(process)
process.kill()
time.sleep(20)
check_exist(process)
```

Comment: I found the solution.

Comment: I found the solution.

The problem is that child process kill by his parent (python script in this case), But it waits for a signal wait(2)  from his parent. 

So in my case, I add the command process.wait(2). and the zombie mode ends.